# laravel5.4 file upload issue 404 Not Found The requested resource /products was not found on this server

Tags: laravel-5.4

I am using Laravel 5.4 and im experiencing a problem. I am currently adding in file upload functionality to my resource product controller. This is done in the standard way using POST and the create and store function.
The code I stared out with and which works just not in the way I want it to.
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

```
$product = new Product;
$product->name = $request->name;
$product->primary_category = $request->primary_category;
$product->secondary_category = $request->secondary_category;
$product->price = $request->price;
$product->stock = $request->stock;
$product->low_stock_level = $request->low_stock_level;
$product->location = $request->location;
$product->description = $request->description;
if($request->hasFile('image')){
  $product->image = $request->image->storeAs('public',$request->name.'.jpg');
  //Storage::putFile('public',$request->file('image'));

  //$request->image->path();
  //$request->image->store('public');
}
$product->active = 0;
$product->weight = $request->weight;
$product->langth = $request->langth;
$product->width = $request->width;
$product->height = $request->height;

$product->save();
return redirect('products/create');
}
```

I then modified the code to this.

public function store(Request $request)
    {

```
$product = new Product;
$product->name = $request->name;
$product->primary_category = $request->primary_category;
$product->secondary_category = $request->secondary_category;
$product->price = $request->price;
$product->stock = $request->stock;
$product->low_stock_level = $request->low_stock_level;
$product->location = $request->location;
$product->description = $request->description;
if(Input::hasFile('image')){
  $file = Input::file('image');
  $file->move('products/', $file->getClientOriginalName());
  $image = '/products/'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
  DB::table('product_images')->insert(
    ['product_id' => $request->product_id, 'image' => $image]
  );
$product->active = 0;
$product->weight = $request->weight;
$product->langth = $request->langth;
$product->width = $request->width;
$product->height = $request->height;

$product->save();
return redirect('products/create');
}
```

This code does not work witch dose not really concern me. What it also dose is creates this error.

404

Not Found

The requested resource /products was not found on this server.

I’m sure that is this modification that is causing the issue as I have reverted to my last stable version and check it worked then i modified the code and got the same error again. 
What is even more wired is this error persists even after the code is change identically back to the last stable version.

Does anyone have any ideas what might be causing this and how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should specify a full path to directory for moving files. For example if you want to move your file to `public/uploads/articles` your code would look like:

```
$file->move(public_path('uploads/articles'), $file->getClientOriginalName());
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion I try it on my last working version and unfortunately, I still get the same error. 
After I run the problematic code the store function is not run on the form submission. This would normal indicate a route problem but the routes have not changed.